# How can I easily back up my Wii U saves/games?

Tags: wii-u

I'm spoiled by being able to back up all of my save/game data on my PS3, PC, Vita etc, so I'm a little concerned that there isn't a straight up "back up all the things" option in the Wii U settings. I've heard some icky backup suggestions like manually copying files.

However, since you can move games/their saves over 100% to an external source (which I should then be able to back up), it seems like if all my game/save content is on an external device I should be able to back up *that device* and keep all my content, right?

So if all my content is on an external drive can I really back it up? Can anything but the Wii U read Wii U formatted external media (it'd probably be an HDD)? If I "restore" the external drive's contents can my Wii U still read the restored contents? And...least likely, if something happens to my Wii U, will I be able to use my external drive's content in any way on a new Wii U system?

Comment: Nintendo is under development of a cloud storage which will (at this moment) come out on 2015-16. But until then, you cannot back-up your games and saves.

Answer (score 1):

I think the general answer to all your questions is “no”.

See more info on [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii-u/631516-wii-u/answers/358344-how-do-you-back-up-wiiu-save-data).

Since the backup only makes full games & saves copy, you won't be allowed to read it on another Wii U without doing an account transfer from your Wii U to the another one.

As a Nintendo & tech enthusiast, that's something I hope they will evolve on. I think we can hope announcements between E3 2015 (june) and E3 2016 (june).

In between, you won't be able to isolate saves.